# Multidimensional and Single Array using array_diff()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Overview of what's gonna happen, For the sake of the example, I provided Email Address, First Name, and Last Name. And each of columns has a check box if the user wants to include it on import or not.

[image]

In this example, `Last Name` wasn't supposed to be included. So when I pass submit, the data of checkbox is being output like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Email Address
    [1] => First Name
)
```

Which is correct, then what **I want to happen** is, to remove the `Last Name` on the original data (multidimensional array), Unfortunately, array_diff() doesn't work, or else I may have did something wrong.

I have these 2 arrays

```
$mapping_import_value = $_SESSION['mapping_import_value'];
$arr_import_column = $_POST['import_column'];
```

**Mapping Import Value:** A multi dimensional array

```
Array
(
    [Email Address] => Array
        (
            [0] => email11@gmail.com
            [1] => email12@gmail.com
            [2] => email13@gmail.com
        )

    [First Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Guy 11
            [1] => Guy 12
            [2] => Guy 13
        )

    [Last Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stand 11
            [1] => Stand 12
            [2] => Stand 13
        )

)
```

Then

**Arr Import Column:** A single array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Email Address
    [1] => First Name
)
```

So it will be like, 2 arrays will match, if something is not matched (Last Name) it will be removed including it's child. So any help would be nice. :D

Comment: It is hard to understand from your descr. Could you provide source data and desired result?

Comment: have you tried `unset`? Like, iterate over the keys of your `mapping_import_value` array using `foreach(array_keys($mapping_import_value) as $key) {` and check if that `$key` is in `$arr_import_column` using `in_array`. If it is not `in_array` use `unset($mapping_import_value[$key])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_interesect_key()`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key), and [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/array_flip) on `$arr_import_column`:

```
$x = array_intersect_key($mapping_import_value, array_flip($arr_import_column));
```

This will basically return all of the entries in `$mapping_import_value` whose keys are present in `$arr_import_column`

Answer (score 2):

Use another variable and iterate like below.

```
$mapping_import_value_another = array();

foreach($arr_import_column as $v)
{
    $mapping_import_value_another[$v] = $mapping_import_value[$v];
}
```

So `$mapping_import_value_another` will have only selected columns data.

Comment: Cleaner than my solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to build a function to check this:

```
function areArraysEqual($arrImportColumn, $mappingImportValue)
{
  foreach($mappingImportValue as $key=>$values)
  {
    if (!in_array($arrImportColumn,$key))
    {
       unset($mappingImportValue[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

This function will remove all keys from `$mappingImportValue` that are not contained in `$arrImportColumn`